# Can I classify elements of a df.column and create a column with the output without iteration (Python-Pandas-Np)?

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, iteration

Given this dataframe,

```
A = pd.DataFrame([[1, 5, 2], [2, 4, 4], [3, 3, 1], [4, 2, 2], [5, 1, 4]],
             columns=['A', 'B', 'C'], index=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
```

I would like to classify the elements of column 'A' according to their size, and create a new column with the output like this:

```
In [26]: A['Size'] = ""
         for index, row in A.iterrows():
             if row['A'] >= 4:
                 A.loc[index, 'Size'] = 'Big'
             if 2.5 < row['A'] < 4:
                 A.loc[index, 'Size'] = 'Medium'
             if 0 < row['A'] < 2.4:
                 A.loc[index, 'Size'] = 'Small'
```

The output would be:

```
Out[27]: 
   A  B  C    Size
 1  1  5  2   Small
 2  2  4  4   Small
 3  3  3  1  Medium
 4  4  2  2     Big
 5  5  1  4     Big
```

Imagine that you have a lot of columns and and different parameters for the same categories, is there a more efficient way to do this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `loc` as a boolean mask to assign just to the rows that meet the criteria, even for such a small df it is faster, for a larger df it will be significantly faster:

```
In [60]:

%%timeit 
A['Size'] = ""
for index, row in A.iterrows():
    if row['A'] >= 4:
        A.loc[index, 'Size'] = 'Big'
    if 2.5 < row['A'] < 4:
        A.loc[index, 'Size'] = 'Medium'
    if 0 < row['A'] < 2.4:
        A.loc[index, 'Size'] = 'Small'
100 loops, best of 3: 2.31 ms per loop
In [62]:

%%timeit
A.loc[A['A'] >=4, 'Size'] = 'Big'
A.loc[(A['A'] >= 2.5) & (A['A'] < 4), 'Size'] = 'Medium'
A.loc[A['A'] < 2.4, 'Size'] = 'Small'

100 loops, best of 3: 1.95 ms per loop
```

Additionally you could use 3 `np.where` conditions which is even faster:

```
In [64]:

%%timeit
A['Size'] = np.where(A['A'] < 2.4, 'Small', np.where((A['A'] >= 2.5) & (A['A'] < 4), 'Medium', np.where(A['A'] >=4, 'Big','')))
1000 loops, best of 3: 828 µs per loop
```

**Update**

Interestingly for a 50,000 row dataframe, the `loc` method outperforms the nested `np.where` method:  I get 4.24 ms versus 12.1 ms.